# Why is "do"/"do script" not working in AppleScript for After Effects 2022

Tags: applescript, extendscript, after-effects

I've been breaking my head for the past few hours trying to solve this.
I've done a lot of research trying to find a clear answer, but no luck so far.

I'm doing some automation tests for an Adobe Suite automated workflow.
I'll be automating Photoshop, InDesign and After Effects files using AppleScript and ExtendScript.

I wrote this test code for InDesign 2021 and it works just fine:

```
set TheTitle to "Test Title"
tell application "Adobe InDesign 2021"
    activate
    open file "path:to:folder:test.indd"
    set jsx_script to "/path/to/folder/test.jsx"
    do script jsx_script language javascript with arguments {TheTitle}
    close every document saving no
    quit
end tell
```

I use the same principle to work with After Effects 2022 and the `do script` portion keeps throwing the `Expected end of line, etc. but found “script”. (-2741)` error.

This is the working version of the script for AE:

```
set jsx_file to "/path/to/folder/test_ae.jsx"
tell application "Adobe After Effects 2022"
    activate
    DoScriptFile jsx_file
end tell
```

If I only type `do` the Script Editor colors it green (as a variable instead of a command). So, neither `do script` nor `do JavaScript` are working.

`DoScriptFile` does run the JSX within AE, but the problem is that I need to pass the variables into the JSX file and `DoScriptFile` won't allow it.

So, I'm looking for either a way to pass arguments/variables to the JSX via `DoScriptFile` or a solution for `do script` not working with AE.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables before doing the script file:

```
set TheTitle to "Test Title"
tell application "Adobe After Effects 2022"
    activate
    DoScript "var TheTitle = \"" & TheTitle & "\";"
    DoScriptFile "/path/to/folder/test_ae.jsx"
end tell
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).